# FailedToNegotiateWithServerError when making connection between NodeJs express api and .net signal r hub

Tags: node.js, signalr-hub, .net-8.0, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

To facilitate real-time communication between a Node.js API and a .NET API, particularly for the scenario of updating a WhatsApp device QR code every 20 seconds using the [text](https://github.com/WhiskeySockets/Baileys) library on the Node.js side and consuming this in a .NET API. and signalR throwing error on connection in nodejs

**Here is the Node Js code**

```
const express = require("express");

const {HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel,HttpTransportType} = require("@microsoft/signalr");



const app = express();

const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("https://localhost:7094/chathub")
.withAutomaticReconnect()
.configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
.build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};


start();
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
  });
```

**Program.Cs**

```
using WA_API;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseCors(cp => cp
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
    .AllowCredentials()
);
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Here is the error message

```
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.522Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.525Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.526Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://localhost:7094/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
Server started on http://localhost:3000
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.632Z] Warning: Error from HTTP request. TypeError: fetch failed.
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.632Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: fetch failed
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.633Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: fetch failed    
[2024-03-13T07:41:34.633Z] Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: fetch failed'.
```

I have tried every solution I can find. like tried http and https and SkipNegotiation and cors policy.

Comment: your error is showing the https url with port is 7094 failing. I would like to suggest you if you are suing self-signed certificate make sure you have placed in the trusted root folder.  also try this code `.withUrl("https://localhost:7094/chathub", { skipNegotiation: true, transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets })` at node.js client to skip Negotiation.